# Unable to get value from provider - ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I have created a provider with constructor code:

```
constructor(private storage: Storage) {

    this.datas = null;
    this.getUserinfoDB()
        .then(
        data => {
            this.uid = data['id'];
            console.log("UID FROM PROVIDER "+this.uid);
        }
    );
}
```

and I just imported it into another ts file:
like:

```
constructor(public crudStorageProvider: CrudStorageProvider) {                
  console.log("UID: " + crudStorageProvider.uid);
}
```

everything is fine with this import and all:

but `console.log("UID: " + crudStorageProvider.uid);` here i am getting undefined.

and my console order is:

```
UID: undefined
UID FROM PROVIDER: 6
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the output *sequence*, it is clear that the data is set after `console.log("UID: " + crudStorageProvider.uid);`.

This is a normal consequence of the asynchronous nature of promises.

You should have a function in your `CrudStorageProvider` instead like so:

```
getUID(){
  if(this.uid){
     return Promise.resolve(this.uid);
  }else{
     return this.getUserinfoDB()
        .then(
        data => {
            this.uid = data['id'];
            console.log("UID FROM PROVIDER "+this.uid);
            return this.uid;
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Then call

```
this.crudStorageProvider.getUID().then((uid)=>  {console.log("UID: ",uid);} )
```

Comment: `getUID` won't return a promise the second time it gets executed. Either the first return inside `getUID` should be wrapped in a promise or the result of `getUID` should be handled conditionally.