# Ionic 3 Angular 4 - Getting session user on load of page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

When a user logs in there object gets saved to the session storage. I have an auth.ts provider which handles the adding/removing and returning of a user from session.

When ever any of my pages load i call the auth provider to get the user.

In this scenario i have an edit-account page where im trying to retrieve the user in storage and save it in a variable calld loggedInUser. However when i console log this variable it returns undefined.

edit-account.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage,NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {User} from "../../providers/user";
import {Auth} from "../../providers/auth";


@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-edit-account',
    templateUrl: 'edit-account.html',
})
export class EditAccountPage {

    account: any;
    loggedInUser: any;


    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                public navParams: NavParams,
                public user: User,
                public auth: Auth) {

        this.loggedInUser = this.auth.getUser();
        console.log(this.loggedInUser);
    }
```

auth.ts (provider)

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Api} from './api';
import {Settings} from './settings';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Storage} from "@ionic/storage";


@Injectable()
export class Auth {
    isLoggedIn: Boolean;
    user: any;

    constructor(public http: Http, public api: Api, public settings: Settings, public storage: Storage) {

        this.storage.get('user').then((user) => {
            this.user = user;
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
        });

    }

    login(user) {

        return this.storage.set('user', user).then(() => {
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
            this.user = user;
        });

    }

    logout() {

        this.storage.remove('user').then(() => {
            this.isLoggedIn = false;
            this.user = null;
        });

    }

    isAuthenticated() {
        return this.isLoggedIn;
    }

    getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue? I have used this same technique on another page and it worked fine, so im unsure why its not working here.

Comment: Who is saving the user in sessionStorage? if you inspect storage with devTools, do you see the user being saved there after login?

Comment: THe user is deffi in session, if i have a button to get the user and click it, it gets the user. This problem i think is because data not loading before the page. Somehow it works on other pages but its not quick enough i guess on this page.

Comment: So now what is the best solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get value from provider - ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097468/unable-to-get-value-from-provider-ionic-2)